# Why setting timeout for wasmer in shell script doesn't work?

Tags: shell, timeout

I want to set a timeout for the wasmer command

```
timeout 5s wasmer hello.wasm
```

the command works correctly from the command line and doesn't time out, but times out when run within a script.

in command line:

```
wuyf@tiger:~/temp/hello/target/wasm32-wasi/release$ timeout 5s wasmer hello.wasm 
Hello, world!
wuyf@tiger:~/temp/hello/target/wasm32-wasi/release$ $?
0: command not found
```

script `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 5s wasmer hello.wasm
```

run the script:

```
wuyf@tiger:~/temp/hello/target/wasm32-wasi/release$ ./run.sh 
wuyf@tiger:~/temp/hello/target/wasm32-wasi/release$ $?
124: command not found
```

Exit code 124 means that the command timed out. why?

Comment: Please revise your question.  Based on what I THINK you want to do, your script is fine, but I don't understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: I have redescribed my question, and I hope it is more helpful to understand.

Comment: what about to test it with '--foreground' `timeout --foreground 5s wasmer hello.wasm`